# Не меняется состояние disable у кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css, валидация

У меня есть валидация формы, и я хочу вешать на кнопку отправки формы disable в случае если не все поля заполнены корректно.
Код проверки на корректность формы:

```
function checkDispatchAvailability() {
  if ((getAvailability(firstDate.value) && getAvailability(secondDate.value)) &&
      (childCount.value + adultCount.value != 0 && adultCount > 0)) {
    popupSubmit.disabled = false;
  } else {
    popupSubmit.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

И на каждом поле внутри формы есть eventListener, внутри которого я вызываю эту функцию.
Один из eventListener'ов:

```
firstDate.addEventListener("change", () => {
    const firstDateMessage = createMessage(getAvailability(firstDate.value));
    firstDateState.textContent = firstDateMessage[0];
    firstDateState.style.color = firstDateMessage[1];
    checkDispatchAvailability();
});
```

Проблема в том, что когда происходит смена поля, на кнопку вешается disable, но после корректирования поля, disable не исчезает, хотя должен. Какие у вас есть идеи на этот счет?

Comment: попробуйте на поля использовать `onkeydown` или `oninput`. `onchange` срабатывает когда вы покидаете поле

Comment: Вы уверены что в функции checkDispatchAvailability() отрабатывают оба условия?

Answer (score 0):

У html forms нет атрибута `disabled` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

То есть форму отключить нельзя только элементы внутри формы.

```js
inputs.ferEach(input => { input.disabled = true });
```

Comment: Дмитрий, popupSubmit - кнопка отправки формы и в этом плане я делаю все правильно, я думаю
popupSubmit.disabled = true/false;

Answer (score 0):

В случае, если валидация не проходит, запрещайте отправку через `event.preventDefault();`
Задизейблить всю форму нельзя - только кнопки и поля